# Does it matter in what matrix mode I call glOrtho?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to learn LWJGL using this tutorial: http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/lwjgl-tutorial-series-a-simple-moving-rectangle/30675/view.html. I wondered what the glOrtho function did so I looked it up. In the opengl docs I read that it does some transformation on the current matrix and is often used on the projection matrix. In the code in the tutorial it calls glOrtho on the modelview matrix. I tried to call glOrtho on the projection matrix and it worked too, so I wonder whether it makes any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. Like any fixed function matrix stack function *glOrtho* will operate on the currently active matrix. It is of uttermost importance to place perspective projections in the projection matrix. And you should do it for orthographic projections as well.

Comment: Then why do they call glOrtho after calling glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) in the tutorial?

Comment: @MaxMeijer: Because whoever wrote it didn't get the memo or is a moron. See http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/projection_abuse.php for the memo.